# find_package(ACL REQUIRED) does not stop processing

Tags: cmake

I am currently trying to set up a CMake-based build system for a small C library of mine. Since this library depends on `libacl`, CMake should verify that it is present on the system, or fail otherwise.

Since there is no predefined `FindACL` module, I used the one from [the KDE project](https://github.com/KDE/kio/blob/7c3e5b9db077122c7d5d9c10c02d42bdd72f1a75/cmake/FindACL.cmake):

```
[...] check_include_files [...] find_library [...]

if (ACL_HEADERS_FOUND AND ACL_LIBS AND ATTR_LIBS)
   set(ACL_FOUND TRUE)
   set(ACL_LIBS ${ACL_LIBS} ${ATTR_LIBS})
   message(STATUS "Found ACL support: ${ACL_LIBS}")
endif (ACL_HEADERS_FOUND AND ACL_LIBS AND ATTR_LIBS)
```

I call it using the following (minimal) `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(
    cmaketest
    VERSION 1.0
    DESCRIPTION "cmake test"
    LANGUAGES C
)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
find_package(ACL REQUIRED) # ACL_LIBS
```

It correctly detects that my system is lacking the `libacl` includes, but does not stop processing, even though the [manual states that](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/find_package.html?highlight=REQUIRED)

> The REQUIRED option stops processing with an error message if the package cannot be found.

Do I have to explicitly check whether `ACL_FOUND` is set, through an `if` statement?

I am using CMake 3.13.4. Terminal output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Looking for include file attr/libattr.h
-- Looking for include file attr/libattr.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sys/xattr.h
-- Looking for include file sys/xattr.h - found
-- Looking for include file sys/acl.h
-- Looking for include file sys/acl.h - not found
-- Looking for include file acl/libacl.h
-- Looking for include file acl/libacl.h - not found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: [redacted]/build
```

Comment: It seems that `FindACL.cmake` script you use is a some **legacy script** (which, however, is used in the modern projects). Could you add some part of that (original!) script to the question post, so changing that script in the repo wouldn't invalidate your question? The part which sets `ACL_FOUND` variable would be definitely sufficient.

Comment: Sure! I have added the relevant part of the `FindACL.cmake` file. The link also points to a specific revision, so it should stay valid as long as the project is not moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that since some time CMake expects a `FindXXX.cmake` script (used in **MODULE** mode of `find_package`) to check *REQUIRED* option and emit an error if needed. Such change in CMake behavior makes old legacy "Find" scripts, like `FindACL.cmake`, to be broken.

Indirect confirmation of that can be found in this "Common bug in find module", described in [CMake wiki](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Find-Libraries#common-bugs-in-find-modules):

> The module does not check _FIND_REQUIRED or
>   _FIND_QUIETLY - and thus the find_package arguments QUIET
>   and REQUIRED will have no effect

So, `FindACL.cmake` script could be rewritten as follows:

```
# FindACL.cmake

# ...

if (ACL_HEADERS_FOUND AND ACL_LIBS AND ATTR_LIBS)
  set(ACL_FOUND TRUE)
  set(ACL_LIBS ${ACL_LIBS} ${ATTR_LIBS})
  message(STATUS "Found ACL support: ${ACL_LIBS}")
elif (ACL_FIND_REQUIRED)
  # ACL hasn't been found but REQUIRED. Emit an error.
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find ACL")
endif (ACL_HEADERS_FOUND AND ACL_LIBS AND ATTR_LIBS)
```

Actually, most "Find" scripts use the special helper which sets result of `find_package` and cares about its options. `FindACL.cmake` could also use this helper:

```
# FindACL.cmake

# ...

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(ACL
  # Use default message on fail.
  DEFAULT_MSG
  # Variables which should be true-evaluated for assume the package to be found
  ACL_HEADERS_FOUND ACL_LIBS ATTR_LIBS
)
```

---

The things are different for `XXXConfig.cmake` scripts, which are processed in **CONFIG** mode of `find_package`. These scripts should only set `XXX_FOUND` variable to false, and CMake will handle REQUIRED option by itself.

Comment: Alright, then I will adjust the script to emit the error itself, as you suggested. Using your explanation I was able to find some hint in an official(?) tutorial which supports your suspicion: [How to find libraries](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Find-Libraries#common-bugs-in-find-modules). Thank you!

Comment: Yes, CMake Wiki could be treated as an "official" guide. Thanks for the link, I have added it to the question post as an confirmation. (Before it, I have checked your code and some its variations on my machine with CMake 3.5).